# How do you compute the list of valid numbers at a certain space in Sudoku?

Tags: java

I'm trying to have a method return the allowed numbers for input at any given spot but the allowed values array is containing values that aren't allowed.
**Note**-I cannot use any packages or anything other than vanilla java(especially **can't** use ArrayList-just saying because it was suggested to me)
Here's my code:

```
  public int[] getAllowedValues(int row, int col){
    int[] allowedValues = new int[9];
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
      allowedValues[i] = i;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
      if(!(board[i][col] == 0)){
        allowedValues[board[i][col]] = 0; //anything with a 0 is illegal, with number means that number is legal
      }
      if(!(board[row][i] == 0)){
        allowedValues[board[row][i]] = 0; //anything with a 0 is illegal, with number means that number is legal
      }
    }
    int rowStart = 0; //rowStart is the top left coord of box the number is in
    if(row <= 3){ 
      rowStart = 1;
    } else if (row <= 6){
      rowStart = 4;
    } else if (row <= 9){
      rowStart = 7;
    }
    int colStart = 0; //colStart is the top left coord of the box the number is in
    if(col <= 3){
     colStart = 1;
    } else if (col <= 6){
     colStart = 4;
    } else if (col <= 9){
     colStart = 7;
    }
    for(int i = rowStart; i < rowStart + 3; i++){
      for(int j = colStart; j < colStart + 3; j++){
        if(!(board[i-1][j-1] == 0)){
          allowedValues[board[i-1][j-1]] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    for(int i = row; i < 9; i++){
      for(int j = col; j < 9; j++){
        if((board[i][j] == 0)){
          allowedValues[board[i][j]] = 0;
        }
        if((board[j][i] == 0)){
          allowedValues[board[j][i]] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    return allowedValues;
  }
```

For some reason the allowed numbers include numbers in the same column/row/square, it varies... Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### The sides

This is homework, and your homework should include learning to debug your own code. (It is an important skill!)

On that note, I strongly recommend that you read Eric Lippert's blog post on ["How to debug small programs"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  And *practice* using the techniques he describes.

You said:

> ... can't use `ArrayList` - just saying *because it was suggested to me*

That was not a good suggestion (IMO).  In your program (i.e. given what the program needs to do), `int[]` is a good choice.  You just made a mistake in the way that you used the array.

---

### The main

The problem with your attempted solution is that the numbers in a Sudoko puzzle go from 1 to 9, but the array indexes for your `allowedValues` array go from 0 to 8.  So, for example:

```
  allowedValues[board[i][col]] = 0;
```

is going to set the wrong array element to zero.  You should be able to figure out how to correct this ... and the other places where you have made the same mistake.